# Ubuntu (WSL) Python separate from Python3.7 Microsoft Store app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Windows 10, the following steps successfully install & run a Python-pyfiglet module:

- Enabled WSL (ran PowerShell as an administrator and entered `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`)
- Installed Ubuntu from Microsoft Store
- Installed Windows Terminal (preview) from Microsoft store
- In Windows Terminal > Ubuntu, I installed Python3 (`sudo apt-get install Python3`)
- In Windows Terminal > Ubuntu, I installed python package pyfiglet (`sudo apt install python3-pyfiglet`)
- In Windows Terminal > Ubuntu > python3, I ran `import pyfiglet` and `print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("Hello World!"))` successfully with expected result!

However, when I try using `import pyfiglet` through any other of the following ways:

1. Python3.7 Store App (installed via Microsoft Store app)
2. Cmd > python3
3. VSCode > create `hello_world.py` and debug,

unfortunately all three methods lead to `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet'`.

Why is `import pyfiglet` successful in Windows Terminal > Ubuntu > Python3, but unsuccessful in all the other three ways to open python? Are these other versions of python separate from the Ubuntu version of python? (I thought they were all the same version of python that essentially comes from WSL.)

If they are all indeed separate python installations, and modules are not shared between them, then how can I reinstall (duplicate) pyfiglet for the Cmd / Python3.7 Store App / VSCode versions? Trying either `sudo apt install python3-pyfiglet` or `pip install pyfiglet` fails in the Cmd / Python3.7 Store App / VSCode debug versions of python.

Comment: The Microsoft Store distribution is Windows Python, not Linux Python. These two versions of Python have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: If you have a `PATH` conflict with `pip` from another version of Windows Python, run it explicitly via the `python3.7` app version, e.g. `python3.7 -m pip install --user pyfiglet`. The "--user" option is required because not even administrators can add system site packages to the app installation.

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks for your reply. What's the difference (differences) between Windows Python and Linux Python? Which one comes from WSL?

Comment: WSL is a kernel extension that allows running native Linux binaries from within a WSL instance, such as is started by running "%SystemRoot%\System32\bash.exe". Within that environment you have an entire Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, and you can install native Linux packages using its package manager, such as `apt` in Ubuntu. You have a root filesystem in this environment, with expected directories such as "/dev" and "/etc", which is located, for example, at "%LocalAppData%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_<...>\LocalState\rootfs", and never to be access directly from Windows.

Comment: The "python3" package in your WSL Linux distro installs a "python3.Y" binary (e.g. "python3.6") in "/usr/bin". This is a native Linux ELF binary, not a Windows PE binary, so it only executes in a WSL environment. It depends on Linux shared libraries (*.so) in "/lib64" and " "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" and a Python standard library in "/usr/lib/python3.Y".

Comment: The Microsoft Store distribution of Python 3.7 is a Windows native application that installs in "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_<...>". It depends on native shared libraries in "%SystemRoot%\System32", and its standard library is located in its "Lib" subdirectory.

Comment: For a particular user, it also installs app-exec links in the user's "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps" folder, including python.exe, python3.exe, python3.7.exe, pip.exe, pip3.exe, and pip3.7.exe. These links allow running the system-installed app. The per-user site-packages is located at "%LocalAppData%\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_<...>\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages".

Comment: @ErykSun Got it! For some reason I thought the latest Windows 10 update (with WSL) was required to install Python 3.7 from the Microsoft Store, leading me to believe WSL is required to install Python 3.7 from the Microsoft Store. I understand I shouldn't have conflated the two.

Comment: @ErykSun Which version of python3 would you say, the WSL Linux-Ubuntu version or the Windows-native Microsoft Store application, is most powerful and most recommended in the dev community? Thanks again!

Comment: It depends on your needs, of course. If you're developing applications for deployment on a Linux server, and you're used to a command-line and terminal workflow such as ssh and vi, then WSL is probably better for you. If you want the best integration with Windows tools and IDEs, then use the Windows version, but not necessarily the Microsoft Store version. For example, Visual Studio installs Python from a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/python), and [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) bundles a complete stack for data analysis.